# Adding Items to ListView on android

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a list view on this XML:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtMsg" />
```

I want to add items to the list view in my code. This is my code:

```
ListView mesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
if(messages.size()>0) {
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, messages);
}
```

messages is an ArrayList of String and is not empty. For some reason the list view is empty on the screen. What should I put instead of android.R.layout.activity_list_item? I think this is my problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: try `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`. Have a look @ http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/activity_list_item.xml `android.R.layout.activity_list_item` has a imageview and textview which you may not need. Do look @ arrayadapter constructors @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html and do set adapter to  listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set adapter of listview 
mesList.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, messages);